# ImportError: cannot import name 'QR'

Tags: python, pycharm, qrcode

Пишу на пайтоне (юзаю Pycharm) декодер QR кодов

```
import qrtools
from qrtools import QR

myqr = QR(filename="/home/user/PycharmProjects/qrcodebot/qrcode.png")
myqr.decode()
print(myqr.data)
```

При компиляции выдает следующее

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/PycharmProjects/qrcodebot/main.py", line 2, in 
>       from qrtools import QR ImportError: cannot import name 'QR'

Как я понял он не видит QR в библиотеке, кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Python интерпретируемый язык, какая компиляция?

Comment: Сорри, опечатался :) , *при запуске

Comment: Как вы устанавливали пакет qrtools?

Comment: Через pycharm проджект интерпретером, через терминал тоже установлен через "sudo apt-get install python-qrtools"

Comment: Попробуйте `from qrtools.qrtools import QR`

Comment: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/qrcodebot/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from qrtools.qrtools import QR
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/qrcodebot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qrtools/qrtools.py", line 28, in <module>
    import zbar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zbar' **

Comment: Zbar не инсталлится, щас попробую че-нибудь сделать, позже отпишусь

Comment: Поздравляю вас с [самым первым багом пакета](https://github.com/primetang/qrtools/issues/1), который уже третий год закрыть не могут.

Comment: А вот сейчас обидно было, ладно потанцую с бубном, либо буду писать свой алогоритм для распознавания, спасибо за отклик :)